# Менять внешние элементы из UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть User Control. Как мне из него получить доступ к другим контролам находящимся на форме на которой он находится?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserControl2 
{
  public mainForm cp1 { get; set; }
  ...
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    if (cp1 != null) 
    {
      cp1.commonPanel.SomeProperty = true;
    }
  }
}

// Внутри одного из методов класса mainForm:
UserControl2 uc2 = ...;
uc2.cp1 = this;
this.Controls.Add(uc2);
```

---

У класса `mainForm` есть `public` свойство `commonPanel`? Видимо - нет. Что пишет про подчеркнутое красным, "non-accessible"? Добавьте в класс  `mainForm`:

```
public CommonPanel CommonPanel { get { return commonPanel; } }
```

и обращайтесь:

```
cp1.CommonPanel ...
```

Comment: Неа, не катит. Мне нужно из userControl'a получить доступ к другим контролам формы на которой он находится. Мб я не правильно выразился

Comment: @MrLalatg Принцип тот же. userControl'у надо типизированные ссылки на все, чем он должен управлять.

Comment: Проблема в том что если я например пишу `public mainForm cp1 { get; set; }` то написав cp1.commonPanel я не достучусь до элемента commonPanel

Comment: @MrLalatg Я не понимаю слово "не достучусь". А до чего Вы достучитесь? На форме есть контрол `commonPanel`? Свойству `cp1` присвоена ссылка на экземпляр формы `mainForm`?

Comment: На форме есть контрол commonPanel? - Да есть. Не очень понимаю как присвоить ссылку на экземпляр, все что написано это - `public mainForm cp1 { get; set; }`

Comment: @MrLalatg Посмотрите изменения кода в ответе.

Comment: Все еще не работает

Comment: @MrLalatg Как Вы думаете, что я могу на это сказать? Я не вижу Вашего кода сквозь монитор (.

Comment: Секунду, простите

Comment: добавил скриншоты кода

Comment: @MrLalatg - _скриншоты кода_ - Дедушка Мороз, подари мне на Новый год лицензию на отстрел скриншотеров...

Comment: @Alexander, у ru.stackoverflow проблемы с выделением кода, что я могу